# Frequency domain convolution vs Time domain multiplication

Tags: matlab

I want to smooth PSD. What I think is I calculated aurocorrelation via xcorr. Then I calculated fourier transform vit fft. Then convolved with gaussian windows. I get smoothed PSD.

According to fourier transform property instead of convolution, I can calculate ifft of PSD(which equal to autocorrelation) and ifft of gaussian window. I can multiply in time domain and I can calculate fourier transform. When I use this way I couldn't get smoothed PSD. Where is the problem?

```
s -> my signal
Rxx1=xcorr(s,288,'biased');%autocorrelation
w=gausswin(5)%gauss windows
F1=dftmtx(M)*(diag(ifft(w,M)))*Rx;%instead of frequency convoluiton I use time domain multiplation 
plot(abs(F1));
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I added matlab short code.